# Get list of all wifi available in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, wifi, nehotspothelper

I have check all possible solutions to get list of all available Wifi's but nothing works for me. 
I even try NEHotspotConfigurationManager API but it connect to wifi with predefined SSID. In my case I need to get the list only.

Do we need entitlement document for NEHotspotNetwork?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 11.0 - Periodically scan for SSIDs (WiFi) nearby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451287/ios-11-0-periodically-scan-for-ssids-wifi-nearby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not still possible in iOS. It doesn't look like there's a way to retrieve a list of currently available SSIDs, without using private APIs which would result in rejection from App Store submission of your app.

Comment: Can you please mention the private API's which can be used.

Comment: @NupurGupta `Apple80211`  check this , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324184/scan-networks-ssids-on-ios-7-by-using-private-api

Comment: For testing purpose, I try to connect using NEHotspotConfiguration with predefined SSID. Now, I need to have signal strength for the connected Wifi. Can you please comment on this?

Comment: @NupurGupta Did you solve it? Is there any sample codes to use NEHotspotConfiguration (objective-c)? I heard that it is available only for iOS 11, does the device need to be jailbroken for it? Thanks.